# MP4's cutting out at the end when streaming FMS 3.5

Tags: flash, ffmpeg, mp4, flash-media-server

I am trying to stream a series of MP4's using FMS3.5 and some of the files seem to cut out a few seconds right before the end. I have used the ffmpeg bat proccess below, and when I increased the framerate to 500 it seems to have corrected itself although that has caused the files to be significantly larger. Was there anyway that I can keep the filesize and framerate lower while avoiding the cutout issue or some predefined settings I should be using when streaming MP4's off FMS 3.5

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -pass 1 -s 572x322 -vcodec libx264 -b 500k -flags +loop+mv4 \
-cmp 256 -partitions +parti4x4+parti8x8+partp4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -me_method hex \
-subq 7 -trellis 1 -refs 5 -bf 0 -flags2 +mixed_refs -coder 0 -me_range 16 \
-g 250 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -qmin 10 -qmax 51 \
-qdiff 4 -acodec libfaac -ab 160k -ac 1 output.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that the streams are, in fact, cut off, possibly by downloading the associated files and viewing them in VLC or another similar player?

I've found that if the player isn't listening for both the stream to stop *and* for the stream's buffer to be empty, it can sound like it's cutting off early because the player might prematurely end playback.

Your mileage may vary, of course, but checking to make sure that the files themselves are actually cut off is definitely worth the time.